# Throwing 10 consecutive heads in 100 throws - why doesn't this work?

Tags: probability

I became interested in the problem of 10 consecutive heads in 100 throws.  I came across a blog entry that said the way to determine this is to determine the probability of NOT getting 10 consecutive heads in your first 10 throws (1 - .5^10 = .999023437) Then you can "slide" that block of 10 forward another 90 times within the 100 throw analysis.  Probability of not getting 10 in a row in this further 90 is .999023437^90 = .915821714  Therefore the probability of achieving 10 in a row is 1 - .915821714 = 8.42%  This made sense to me but is wrong.

I later discover the Markov chain method and calculated the probability at 4.413%  I wrote a simulation and after 600 runs came up with a very similar number so I believe the 4.413% is correct.

My struggle is I can't explain why the first method gives an answer that is not even close to correct.  It would seem that the coin flips are independent of each other so the idea of "sliding" this block of 10 forward until we get to 100 seems like it should work as it covers all consecutive groupings of 10 that can be made.  Clearly it doesn't work though, but I'd be interested in hearing if anyone with good probability knowledge could explain why it doesn't work. There is clearly something wrong with the logic but I can't put my finger on it.

Comment: The events of getting heads on 1 through 10, and of getting heads on 2 through 11, are most certainly not independent.

Comment: You're overcounting the number of ways to get 10 in a row by a whole lot.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2219948/probability-of-flipping-10-000-coins-and-getting-at-least-one-10-consecutive-hea/2231216#2231216

Comment: I can certainly see that 1 through 10 and 2 through 11 contain 9 of the same flips.  But isn’t each flip independent of all others?  Yet it feels intuitively like there is a connection.  What is it about the process that makes them dependent?  I feel like my brain is close to understanding, but not quite there.